# Using HighCharts with vb asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, highcharts

I am trying to use Highcharts to see if it will work for me but I can't get anything to load.

I downloaded the samples but they don't work with Visual Studio 2010, I downloaded a trial of Visual Studio 2013 and i get the error 'HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error'

I have tried several very simple sample codes but with VS2010 but I keep getting a blank screen.

I really need a starting point to learn how to use Highcharts to see how they could improve my current web software that uses very basic google charts with Json.

Comment: The [Highcharts demo site](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) has lots of examples, which you can then view on jsfiddle, eg http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bit of trouble getting them to display at first, too. It's just a matter of figuring out all the missing pieces, which unfortunately can be tedious if you don't know what you're doing.
Guessing you checked out the JSfiddle demos. If you couldn't get that code to work in your project, try searching for VS 2010 highcharts projects until you find one that works. Then you can break it down from there.

I would offer more specific help, but I'm using VS 2015 and C#

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at JSfiddle as I haven't yet

Comment: Got it working with Javascript inside vb -Thanks. Now need to try and get it working using VB code!

Comment: That's at least half the battle I would think